# Can a Hindu turned Muslim divorcee convert back to Hindu

Tags: nikah, women, talaq, apostasy

Can a Muslim divorcee (who was Hindu before marrying a Muslim) converts back to Hindu after divorce?

Comment: According to who?  Obviously, Muslims aren't going to encourage Muslims to convert away from Islam, so I'm not sure what exactly you're expecting in an answer here that isn't more political in nature than religious.

Comment: Appreciate your time, I think I am very clear as far as my question is concerned. As a matter of fact I am here in this platform to ask religion related questions only and as I am not a Muslim so I am a asking if the religion allows or not. There ain't any political intentions perhaps I am expecting a fair opinion of the experts straight forwardly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it entirely depends on which country you are in. Please be careful while converting back to Hinduism leaving Islam, because in some countries who will charged to death for abandoning Islam. But, mostly in non Islamic countries, this doesn't apply anyways. This [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy_in_Islam#Apostasy_in_the_recent_past) article of 'Apostasy in Islam' gives a fair picture as to in which countries execution is the prescribed punishment for apostasy.

Next, lies, "**Can** a Muslim divorcee ...???" At first place, in Islam, there is distinction between Muslim and Mumin (believer). So, I guess, you're talking about a Muslim only. Then there wouldn't be any problem for a Muslim who wasn't a Mumin at first place to abandon his religion. But if one was a perfect Mumin, he/she wouldn't even think of this question.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: It would probably be best to remove, "But if one was a perfect Mumin, he/she wouldn't even think of this question." 

Due to the fact it is subjective, and being Mumin, still allows one to ask questions of fiqh, which is exactly what this question is. (Imām Shafi'i, Imām Ḥanīfah all thought of this question, and addressed it, and are viewed as Mumin.) 

I would edit your answer, but I would not want to alter the meaning as that is not allow.